# weird NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I encountered a weird error:

```
mycon.Open();

adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Employee; Select * from Shift; select * from Has_Shift", mycon);
adap.TableMappings.Add("T1", "Employee");
adap.TableMappings.Add("T2", "Shift");
adap.TableMappings.Add("T3", "Has_Shift");

adap.Fill(ds);

DataRow newRow = ds.Tables["T1"].NewRow();
newRow["Name"] = textBox1.Text;
ds.Tables["T1"].Rows.Add(newRow);
adap.Update(ds);
mycon.Close();
```

There is an **error** stating:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object at the DataRow newRow line.

I don't know why is it happening.

Comment: Where are you initializing `ds`?

Comment: @JeremyTodd, `adap.Fill(ds);`

Comment: That doesn't initialize the dataset, it just populates it with data (although I'd expect it to throw an exception if `ds` were null).

Comment: I tried, but the information in the dataset ds is too complicated, I also think the problem lies in the adap.Fill(ds), maybe I am missing some parameters? I initialize Dataset ds = new Dataset() top of this piece of code.

Comment: The question is, where is the error pointing to, which line?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line with the error. Start debugging. When the breakpoint is hit, inspect the actual contents of `ds` at that time. Learning to use the debugger will make you a lot more productive in the long run, and will server you better here than us making random guesses about code that we (mostly) cannot see.

Comment: Doesn't `adap.TableMappings.Add("T1", "Employee");` mean that the table will be in the dataset as `ds.Tables["Employee"]` rather than `ds.Tables["T1"]`?

Comment: (Maybe incidental, may actually be the problem - I think your two string parameters to the [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tfw9bx3.aspx) method are the wrong way around - it's meant to be `sourceTable,dataSetTable`)

Comment: @vonv. The DataRow newRow = ds.Tables["T1"].NewRow()

Comment: @hvd and Damien_The_Unbeliever Oh is that error? But I tried both using the same name but it still gives me the same error, as in both using adap.TableMappings.Add("Employee", "Employee");

Comment: @EdinsonTan if you changed T1 to Employee shouldn't you write it like: DataRow newRow = ds.Tables["Employee "].NewRow() ?

Comment: @AdilMammadov Ya.. I know, I change that too but still gives me the error..

Comment: please, look if ds.Tables["Employee "] is null or not

Answer (score 0):

> If you use a batch SQL statement to retrieve multiple tables and fill
>   a DataSet, the first table is named using the table name specified to
>   the Fill method. Subsequent tables are named using the name specified
>   to the Fill method plus a number starting from one and incrementing by
>   one. For example, if you were to run the following code: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx)

So the code will be

```
adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Employee; Select * from Shift; select * from Has_Shift", mycon);

// second table name will be Employee +1
adap.TableMappings.Add("Employee1", "Shift");
// second table name will be Employee +2
adap.TableMappings.Add("Employee2", "Has_Shift");

// give Table name as below 
adap.Fill(ds, "Employee");

DataRow newRow = ds.Tables["Employee"].NewRow();
newRow["Name"] = textBox1.Text;
ds.Tables["Employee"].Rows.Add(newRow);
adap.Update(ds);
mycon.Close();
```

Since here we gave `"Employee"` as table name in Fill method, first table will be `"Employee"` and second will be `"Employee1"` and third will be "Employee2"

Since you haven't given any table name your table names will be "Table", "Table1", "Table2" ...
You can map them to correct name

```
adap.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Employee");
adap.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Shift");
adap.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "Has_Shift");
```

and rest of the code will be

```
adap.Fill(ds);

DataRow newRow = ds.Tables["Employee"].NewRow();
newRow["Name"] = textBox1.Text;
ds.Tables["Employee"].Rows.Add(newRow);
adap.Update(ds);
mycon.Close();
```